# Multiplying two integers with sizes 8N in C

Tags: c, multiplication, bit-shift

I'm trying to multiply 2 integers each of size 8N, for even N. Both numbers are positive, and I have to do that by multiplying each time 8 bits on 16 bits.
This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned createMask(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
   unsigned r = 0;
   for (unsigned i=a; i<=b; i++)
       r |= 1 << i;

   return r;
}

int multiplicator(int a, int b)
{
    int shift = 0;
    int prod = 0;
    int curr_a=a;
    int curr_b=b;
    
    while(curr_b > 0)
    {
        int curr_shift= shift;
        unsigned int b_val = curr_b & createMask(curr_shift, curr_shift + 16);
        
        if(b_val > 0)
        {
           while( curr_a > 0)
           {
               unsigned int temp_prod = b_val *(curr_a & createMask(curr_shift, curr_shift + 8));
               temp_prod = temp_prod << curr_shift;
               prod += temp_prod;
               curr_shift += 8;
               curr_a = curr_a >> 8;
              
           }
        }
        curr_b = curr_b >> 16; // Shift to the next 16 bits of B
        shift += 16;
    }
    
    return prod;
}
```

It works fine on pretty small numbers, so I guess the problem occures when I am trying to shift, but as I am new to working with bits instead of the numbers I don't know how to fix this.

This works:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 124;
    int b = 238;
    
    
    int prod = multiplicator(a, b);
    printf("our prod is: %d", prod);
    

    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 8967; //this doesn't work
    int b = 56432;
    
    
    int prod = multiplicator(a, b);
    printf("our prod is: %d", prod);
    

    return 0;
}
```

***Edit:
working code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned createMask(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
   unsigned r = 0;
   for (unsigned i=a; i<=b; i++)
       r |= 1 << i;

   return r;
}

int multiplicator(int a, int b)
{
    int shift = 0;
    int prod = 0;
    int curr_a=a;
    int curr_b=b;
    
    while(curr_b > 0)
    {
        int curr_shift= shift;
        unsigned int b_val = curr_b & createMask(0, 15);
        
        if(b_val > 0)
        {
           while( curr_a > 0)
           {
               unsigned int temp_prod = b_val *(curr_a & createMask(0,7));
               temp_prod = temp_prod << curr_shift;
               prod += temp_prod;
               curr_shift += 8;
               curr_a = curr_a >> 8;
              
           }
        }
        curr_b = curr_b >> 16; // Shift to the next 16 bits of B
        shift += 16;
    }
    
    return prod;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very indirect way of multiplying two numbers. Just out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish, bignum multiplication? Or is this an assignment?

Comment: Actually I think your combination of shifting and masking is doubled. When you shift curr_b 16 bits to the right, you do not need to create a mask from bit 16 to 31, but instead from 0 to 15 to get the "next" 16 bits of curr_b. So if I read that correctly, you only need one of both.

Comment: @PhilMasteG It's not really an assignment- I'm trying to right a pseudo code of how it should work to understand it better. And I'm failing a bit

Comment: @SpaceNugget "each of size 8N, for even N" --> simpler as "each of size 16M"

Comment: Compiling with all warnings enabled might allow the compiler to tell you what it thinks of your code.